The console output is not displayed when calling from Irvine, but it returns a value to 'c', which can then be printed on the console
main.c

#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    // Declare the assembly function
    extern int add_func(int a, int b);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

int main() {

    printf("Starting the assembly function...\n");
    int result = add_func(2, 3);
    printf("Result: %d\n", result);

    return 0;
}



Include irvine32.inc

.model flat, STDCALL

.data
    result DWORD ?
    
.code

add_func PROC

    ; Save the base pointer
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    ; Get the arguments
    mov eax, [ebp+8]  ; a
    mov ecx, [ebp+12] ; b

    ; Add a and b
    add eax, ecx

    ; Store the result in a variable
    mov result, eax
    
    call WriteInt

exit_function:

    ; Restore the base pointer
    pop ebp

    ; Return the result in EAX
    mov eax, result
    ret 8  ; Clean up the stack (2 arguments * 4 bytes each)

add_func ENDP

END



No Output for Irvine WriteInt

I want to use assembly to write to the console or perform other standard calls. My environment is set up properly for regular assembly; it prints to the console easily using write int. However, I need to ensure that the setup works for other standard calls as well.
Successful Runing only .asm with irvine32

Does WriteInt add a newline?  Is it's output buffered?

Are you sure the code you are showing is the code you are using? In the C code you are using the CDECL (C) calling convention but in the assembly code you are using STDCALL for add_func. I would think that wouldn't even link because of the incompatible name mangling. I think your problem ultimately has to do with mixing calling conventions.

As an example this uses CDECL (C) calling convention: https://pastebin.com/CEdSBc4C . Notice I have used add_func PROC C instead of add_func PROC to override the default STDCALL convention set by the .MODEL directive. RET 8 has been replaced by RET. A better version uses the PROC directive to define the arguments a and b and also uses the arguments by name. When arguments are added to PROC prologue and epilogue code to set up a stack frame (with EBP) is automatically added by MASM. That version is here:
https://pastebin.com/58QdV1jP

@stark I don't know

@Michael Petch you are right I’m currently using irvine32.inc to write to the console in assembly. However, if you could provide a solution to write to the console without relying on any additional libraries or resources, that would be great.

With the versions of the assembly code I gave in my previous links (pastebin) it worked as expected. The C++ code worked and the assembly code that uses irvine32 also worked. That was with Visual Studio 2019 and 2022. Did you modify irvine32.inc or any of the header files and are you sure the code you actually showed in your question is what failed? I still can't see how what you provided here would actually link without error.

@MichaelPetch Thank you so much learned a lot.   One more thing instead of Irvine another way to directly call windows console write syscall

For simple text output you can use GetStdHandle to get the stdout handle and use writefile to output text to the console. An example is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6350545/3857942  . There is also WriteConsoleOutput that can be used as well, but a bit more complex.

ThanksGiving Michael Petch
Include irvine32.inc

; irvine32.inc already uses this directive for us:
; .model flat, STDCALL

.data
result DWORD ?

.code

add_func PROC C

    ; Save the base pointer
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    ; Get the arguments
    mov eax, [ebp+8] ; a
    mov ecx, [ebp+12] ; b

    ; Add a and b
    add eax, ecx

    ; Store the result in a variable
    mov result, eax

    call WriteInt

    exit_function:

    ; Restore the base pointer
    pop ebp

    ; Return the result in EAX
    mov eax, result
    ret

add_func ENDP

END

